# Is possible to redefine application's shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, shortcut

In one application (`SomeApp`) I want redefine the `CMD-N` (build-in) shortcut (New Window) to run automator-script.

So, when I press `CMD-N` it should run my Automator apple-script instead of the **New Window** built-in command, but exactly in one application only.

Already done:

1. I opened the Automator and created a simple `service`.
2. `no input` in the `SomeApp`.
3. It contains the `run shell script` action
4. and the script is `open -a SomeApp http://www.google.com` (opening an URL)
5. of course, the script itself is working flawlessly (i know how to using Automator)
6. Tested, saved, named it as: `SomeAppUrl`
7. In the `SomeApp` the `CMD-N` is currently used for the "New Window" (builtin) command.
8. I want replace this already existing shortcut with the my Automator service described above.
9. I know the `system preferences` -> `keyboard` -> `shortcuts`

**BUT**

- in the `services` i could choose a shortcut - but it will be a global
- or in the `App shortcuts` could choose for the given `SomeApp` the "New Window" and assigning a new shortcut

But no one REPLACING the current (built-in) `Cmd-N` with my `SomeAppUrl` Automator service ONLY in the `SomeApp`.

Is this possible? If yes, could please someone add some hints?

### EDIT

For the fast-commenters:

1. The current state: the `CMD-N` opening a "New window".
2. The final state: the `CMD-N` should run my own Automator script...
3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* settings are, e.g. in **macOS Catalina**,... **Workflow receives [no input] in [SomeApp]** and it's assigned the *keyboard shortcut* of **⌘N** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, it is not global in the sense that now **⌘N** in every *application* is going to run that *Service/Quick Action*. Only the *application* defined as **SomeApp** is going to receive the **⌘N** *keyboard shortcut*.

This of course means that **SomeApp** must have focus to receive the **⌘N** *keyboard shortcut* assigned to the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*.

Therefore, in order to have **SomeApp** respond to **⌘N** as the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* the **New Window** *command* of **SomeApp** must be reassigned to e.g. **⌥N** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**.

Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**<sup>1</sup> and click the **[+]** *button*.

- For **Application:** select the target *application* (**SomeApp**).
- For **Menu Title:** use **New Window** (Or exactly what is on the menu for the *command* you want to change.)
- For **Keyboard Shortcut:** use, e.g.,: **⌥N** (Assuming no other *command* is using that one in that *application*. **You** must determine that, e.g., **⌥N**, or whatever you change it to, is not already in use.)

Then click the **Add** *button*.

Now when **SomeApp** has focus and you press **⌘N** the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* will be triggered.

---

**Notes:**

When a *keyboard shortcut* is assigned to an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, it is only *global* if the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* is set to **... in [any application]**, and when set to **SomeApp** it only appears in that *applications* **Services** menu.

I have found in some cases pressing the assigned *keyboard shortcut* may not trigger the first time and that manually triggering it once from the **Services** *menu* takes care of that.

Additionally keep in mind that all of this assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>See [Create keyboard shortcuts for apps on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac) for additional information.</sub>

Comment: @jm666, Wow! Was I shocked to see I have a +100 showing on the reputation changed icon. I didn't even know there was a bounty on the question. **Thank you** so much for the biggest bounty I've received thus far!